# empty groovy range

Tags: groovy

Is it possible to construct an empty range? Something that would satisfy the following test:

```
  Range emptyRange = // the magic goes here
  assert emptyRange.from == null
  assert emptyRange.to == null
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
Range emptyRange = new EmptyRange()
```

Comment: thanks, I was thrown off by the docs which indicate you need to provide a constructor arg and I had no idea what to pass. But in fact, it seems you don't http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/EmptyRange.html#constructor_summary

Comment: @Don yeah, the docs could be better, as it [says in the source](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/lang/EmptyRange.java) _at can be `null`_